# generate specific numbers for row and column in java

Tags: java, algorithm, math

i want to write a code that makes a specific numbers in the loop .

for example generate numbers like this :

```
 column 1 - row 1 

 column 1 - row 2  

 column 1 - row 3
```

and then generate this ( for example):

```
column 2 - row 1 

column 2 - row 2  

column 2 - row 3 

column 2 - row 4
```

is there any way to write this Algorithm ? thank you so much

code , i have a code like this but i want to manage it :

```
     boolean[][] mapEq = new boolean[mapWidth][mapHeight];
    int free = mapWidth * mapHeight;

    int randomFree = ((int) (free * Math.random()));

    int x = 0, y = 0;


   for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {
            if (!mapEq[i][j]) {
                if (k == randomFree) {
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    break SearchRandom;
                } else {
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it creat a random thing but i want to make a specific number for example

for column 1 - row 1 and row 2 and row 3

and for column 2 - row 1 and row 2 and row 3 and row 4

Comment: Did you try to do anything yourself?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to achieve with your algorithm. I suggest that you start coding and get back to us, once you have some specific problems or questions. Good luck!

Comment: yes i did but i cant

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do... You mean each "column" will have different number of "rows"? Depending on what?

Comment: what you did? and what is the problem?

Comment: i tryed to make a loop which do this to me but Instead make for example  column 1 - row 2 ,, column 1 row 3 ,, makes column 1 row 1 and column 2 row 2 for example

Comment: provide your code what you have tried.

Comment: It seems to me a loop inside a loop would be enough, maybe I'm not understanding the complexity of the problem?

Comment: i added the code which i have to change

Comment: what is your desired input and output that your expecting?

Comment: look code above is completly random but i want to mange to algorithm for example i want the out put be Manageable for example for column1 make row numbers 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 but for column 2 make row number 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
int[] columnLengths = {3, 4}; // Lengths of the columns

for(int i = 0; i < columnLengths.length; i++) { // Loop the columns
    for(int j = 0; j < columnLengths[j]; j++) { // Loop the rows
        System.out.println("column " + i + " - row " + j);
    }
}
```

I am really not sure what you are trying to make, but this is what I understood.

Comment: it is a simpler then that i want but yes its close to what i want thank you man